how to detect screenshot capture event when screenshot event is disabled using flutter windowmanager?
I have disabled the screenshot functionality using Flutter WindowManager, and now I want to detect if the user tries to take a screenshot and display a toast message , snackbar or custom bottomsheet informing them that screenshots are disabled for this app.
i have disabled the screenshot functionality using this code.
import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';
bool secureMode = false;
_initSecureMode();
 Future<void> _initSecureMode() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(
        FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
    setState(() {
      secureMode = true;
    });
  }

